# How to make webpage responsive? Using Media Queries, still the page is unresponsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am adding CSS and the HTML code I had written. Basically want to understand why the media query is not working even though I applied the responsiveness concept.

Apart from responsiveness, it would be great, if someone could guide me how to move the right side column/line coming in username exactly with the horizontal line coming on username. Similarly, I want that vertical column line on password field also.

Adding images after I achieved responsiveness following the recommendation to use bootstrap without overlapping.

1. The right side border is cut off.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7oFw.png)
2. I am providing an image of another item I need help on and had asked initially as well. The item marked in yellow is incorrect. I need that line like I have used vertical line with green color for both the text fields, username and password.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Dsy.png)
3. I want the vertical line I had for 2 partitions, i.e. class firstChild and secondChild to appear only on Desktop/iPAD. It should disappear on mobile. Right now its appearing on mobile as highlighted below.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6ODL.png)

```css
.modal-header .header {
            padding: 40px 40px 0;
            position: relative;

      }

      input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
        width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 40px !important;
    border: 0;
    background: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-size: 16px;
      }

      label {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;

      }



      .modal-header .header .modal-title{
            margin-bottom: 32px;
            font-size: 28px;
            line-height: 32px;
            font-weight: 300;
            border-bottom: 0;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color: #05164d;
        }

     .modal .modal-dialog {
            position: relative;
            margin: 30px auto;
            background: #fff;
            max-width: 836px;
     }

    .close {
            margin-bottom: 32px;
            font-size: 18px;  
            line-height: 20px;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #52627c;
         }

    .close:hover{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #52627c;
     }

     .parentBox {
        width: 100%;
    max-width: 335px;
     }

/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
.parent{
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.parent>div {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.parent .secondHalf {
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.checkBox {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 12px !important;
}
.inputText{
padding-bottom: 24px;
}
.inputText::after{
    position:absolute;
    width: 2.5px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #666;
    content: '';
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 335px;
}

.links::after{
    background-image: url("https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/48/000000/arrow.png");
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    top: 7px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
.links{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 23px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #52627c;
    display: block;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.btnbox{
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    padding: 11px 30px !important;
    min-width: 150px;
    background: #ffad00;
    border: 0;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.forgotPassword
{
margin-top: 30px;
}
fieldset {
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    
  <h2>Modal Heading</h2>
  
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class = "header">  
          <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
        </div>
            <div class = "header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="color: #52627c;">Close &times;</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="parent">
          <div class = "firstHalf col-6">
            <form>
                <fieldset class="parentBox">
            <fieldset class="fieldset">
                <div class>
                <div class="inputText">
                    <input class="form" placeholder="Enter Username" type="text" value>
                </div>

                <div class="inputText">
                    <input class="form" placeholder="Enter Password" type="password" value>
                </div>

                <div class="checkBox">
                    <label for="chck">
                    <input class="chck" id="chck" name="chck" onclick type="checkbox">
                    Keep me Logged in
                </label>
                </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="btnField">
                <button class="btnbox" id="btn" type="button">
                    <span class="btnLabel">Login</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="forgotPassword">
                <div>
                    <a href="https://www.google.com" class="links">Forgotten your Username?
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                <a href="https://www.google.com" class="links">Forgotten your Password?
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
            

        <div class = "secondHalf col-6">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h3>I am trying for the first time</h3>
                    <p>With your personal Username, you can access all the accounts. At any time and from anywhere, whether you are home or on the move.</p>
                         <p>Yourpersonal details</p>
                         <p>Faster services</p>
                         <p>Status of all your inquiries</p>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="https://www.google.com" class="links">Register here
                    </a>

            </div>



        </div>
        
    </div>
        
    
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The `.col-6` class from Bootstrap has `max-width: 50%;` on it which overrides `width` properties. Is that your problem?

Comment: If you want to use bootstrap, do not override their classes (`col-1`, `col-2`, etc.)
Other than that, the use of media query is correct.

Comment: If you copy paste my code and open the resulting HTML page, you would see that my page has 2 sections under header. I have created 2 classes for them, firstChild and secondChild. I would like them to be overlapping on mobile, i.e. content under class firstChild comes first on top and then content under class secondChild. Which means unlike right now, where both the sections are partitioned vertically as 50%, on mobile they should be one after another and take entire 100% space on mobile. 

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### About the media query question

If you are using Bootstrap, you should go with their classes and not overwrite them. Your media query is not working because it tries to overwrite an existing Bootstrap class in the wrong way. (If you really want to overwrite it, **which you shouldn't**, you can probably use more [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) or use `!important`)

That said, you can simply use the right column classes to achieve what you want (on mobile the 2 sections should be on top of each other):

```html
<div class="firstHalf col-12 col-md-6">
  /* Your content here */
</div>
<div class="secondHalf col-12 col-md-6">
  /* Your content here */
</div>
```

Check the [official docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options) for more info.

### About the vertical line question

You are already using `border-bottom` to set the "horizontal line" (as you called it) in the username input. You can add a `border-right` with the same properties and remove the `::after`, so a "vertical line" will be aligned with the "horizontal line":

```css
/* Delete this class: */
.inputText::after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2.5px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #666;
  content: '';
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 335px;
}

/* Update this class: */
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 40px !important;
  border: 0;
  background: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
  /* include this: */
  border-right: 2px solid #666;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 16px;   
}
```